# Avoiding SQL Injections to the Stored Procedure in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, special-characters, sql-injection

How to avoid SQL injections from Node.js when the calls are made to the stored procedure

Suppose from the front End of the UI if I entered some special characters 
Eg.:

- If `?` is entered `true` will be saved to the database
- If `??` is entered `` `true` `` will be saved to the database

**For some special characters such as Backslashes(`\`) and Apostrophes (`'`)**

I will be getting these types of errors from the console

```
From console: '
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
 '''')' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:200:25)
    at Object.saveFeeds (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\middleware\db.js:96:15)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\middleware\routes.js:187:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'\'\')\' at line
1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'CALL AddFeedItems(1,\'\'\')' }
undefined
C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type undefined
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:595:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\middleware\routes.js:188:17
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\middleware\db.js:100:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\xampp\htdocs\nodechat\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
```

**routes.js**

```
app.post('/AddFeedItems', function(req, res) {
        // console.log(req.body);
        try{
            console.log(JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0]));
            req.body = JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0]);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Error');
            req.body = req.body
        }
        db.saveFeeds(req.body, function(chats) {
            res.write(JSON.stringify(chats));
            res.end();
        })
});
```

**db.js**

```
function saveFeeds(data,cb) {
    const conn = createConnection();
        conn.connect();
        console.log('From console'+data.keyword);
        let  sql ="CALL AddFeedItems("+data.senderid + ",'" + data.keyword + "')";
         conn.query(sql, true,function(err,result) {
           if(err) console.log(err);
            conn.end();
             console.log(result);
            cb(result); 
        });
}
```

**MySQL Stored Procedures**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddFeedItems`(IN `senderid` BIGINT(255), IN `keyword` VARCHAR(255)) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
DECLARE LastFeedId INT; 
INSERT INTO `feed_item` (`userid`, `content`, `timestamp`, `likes`, `comments`, `user_flag`, `likes_data`) VALUES (senderid, keyword, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0, 0, 0, 'like'); 
SET LastFeedId = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
INSERT INTO `feed_item_likes` (`feed_item_id`, `user_id`, `timestamp`, `is_like`) VALUES (LastFeedId, senderid, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 0); 
SELECT LastFeedId; 
END
```

In general, In order to prevent these special characters injections into the SQL. What are the necessary steps and precaution should be adopted in the code?

---

### Edit:

Need a function to strip off a set of special character's like Backslashes(**`\`**), Dollars(**`$`**), Apostrophes (**`'`**) and Question Marks(**`?`**) from Node.js

So I found the solution to replace all the above special characters, except for the Question Marks(**`?`**).

**These were the following results obtained:**

***With question mark in regex***

**`data.keyword.replace(/[\\$'"\?]/g, "\\$&")`**

```
+-----------+-----------+
|Entered    |Saved into |
|Character  |Database   |
+-----------+-----------+
| ?         | rue       |
| ??        | rue?      |
| ???       | ???       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

***Without question mark in regex***

**`data.keyword.replace(/[\\$'"]/g, "\\$&")`**

```
+-----------+-----------+
|Entered    |Saved into |
|Character  |Database   |
+-----------+-----------+
| ?         | true      |
| ??        | `true`    |
| ???       | ???       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Tried out with built-in functions,

1. **`var key = mysql.escape(data.keyword);`**
2. **`var key = conn.escape(data.keyword);`**

> ```
> let sql ="CALL AddFeedFriendItems("+data.senderid + "," + data.friendid + ",'" + data.friendusername + "'," + key + ")";
> ```

**Still the result is not favoring, Question Marks(`?`) will be stored as `true`.**

I need to replace those Question Marks(**`?`**) with only **`?`** value. Instead, **`true`** or **`rue`** value will be stored into the database.

***How am I supposed to write the regex to match the question mark and replace with the same characters only?***

---

Without the MySQL Stored Procedures, replacing the above **`saveFeeds()`** in `db.js`

**Data will be stored in a proper manner**

```
function saveFeeds(data,cb){
    const conn = createConnection();
        conn.connect();
        conn.query(
            "INSERT INTO feed_item (userid, content, timestamp, likes, comments, user_flag, likes_data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [data.senderid, data.keyword, data.timestamp, 0, 0, 0, 'like'],
            function (err, rows) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var feedId = rows.insertId;
                    var feedId = rows.insertId;
                    conn.query(
                        "INSERT INTO feed_item_likes (feed_item_id, user_id, timestamp, is_like) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [feedId, data.senderid, data.timestamp, 0],
                        function (err, rows) {
                            if(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                var feedId = rows.insertId;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                conn.end();
                cb(feedId);
            }
          );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I found the solution with Regex + Unicode + Built-in function

```
var key = conn.escape(data.keyword);
var keyword = key.replace(/[?]/g, "❓");

let  sql ="CALL AddFeedFriendItems("+data.senderid + "," + data.friendid + ",'" + data.friendusername + "'," + keyword + ")";
```

[List of Unicode Characters with Question Mark](https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=QUESTION)

By Default Collation will be set to `latin1_swedish_ci` in MySQL. This confuses whether which type of characters to be saved. So naturally, it will be saved in the plain text format`?`. Although In general for any Unicode character `?` will be saved in the DB. Since Collation is set to `latin1_swedish_ci`

*Note: Need some research about saving Unicode characters into MySQL will hinder performance or retrieving records by B-Tree index's raise any other issues. Since `.replace()` will degrade performance further when more than 999K messages are stored. Because
By Default Collation will be set to `latin1_swedish_ci` in MySQL*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your stored procedure, it's in your CALL statement:

```
sql: 'CALL AddFeedItems(1,\'\'\')' }
```

This results in an SQL statement:

```
CALL AddFeedItems(1,''')
```

Three `'` quotes in a row is not valid syntax. It's throwing a syntax error on the CALL statement, it never gets past that to run the stored procedure.

If you want a quoted string containing a literal single-quote, the SQL must be one of the following forms:

```
CALL AddFeedItems(1,'''') -- two single-quotes become one literal single-quote 
CALL AddFeedItems(1,'\'') -- escaped single-quote
CALL AddFeedItems(1,"'") -- delimit by alternative quotes, if sql_mode is not ANSI
```

Comment: Hello Karwin, Being an Oracle ACE Director will you just suggest me any changes needed to be adapted to my post answer and thanks for analyzing the root cause.